# C# split the postional file data in groups

Tags: c#, file, split

Given this positional file example above, where I have 2 "data groups", which are the combination of "Header, a Body list, and a Footer", I want to split the string so that it separates them into those groups.
That is, when I apply the split in this scenario, I get returned 1 list with 2 two substrings, where each element in the list is a string that contains only 1-group data.

However, I have to take into account, that if it is a positional file, the FOOTER ends the truth in position 300, in other words, after the "POSITIONAL DATA" I will have an additional 300 characters of white space or some data.

Is there a simple way to do this using split?

> HEADER        SOME POSITIONAL  DATA
>   BODY          POSITIONAL FOO BAR1  2018-06-18
>   BODY          POSITIONAL FOO BAR2  2018-05-15
>   FOOTER        POSITINAL DATA
>   HEADER        SOME POSITIONAL  DATA 2
>   BODY          POSITIONAL FOO BAR1  XXXX-XX-XX
>   BODY          POSITIONAL FOO BAR2  XXXX-XX-XX
>   BODY          POSITIONAL FOO BAR3  XXXX-XX-XX
>   BODY          POSITIONAL FOO BAR4  XXXX-XX-XX
>   FOOTER        POSITINAL DATA 2

Example method:

```
   public void ProcessPositionalFile(string filePath)
    {
        var dataExample = @"
                            HEADER SOME POSITIONAL DATA
                            BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR1 2018-06-18
                            BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR2 2018-05-15
                            FOOTER POSITINAL DATA
                            HEADER SOME POSITIONAL DATA 2
                            BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR1 XXXX-XX-XX
                            BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR2 XXXX-XX-XX
                            BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR3 XXXX-XX-XX
                            BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR4 XXXX-XX-XX
                            FOOTER POSITINAL DATA 2";

        // Expected Result of method SplitDataInBlocks
        // List<string> groups = SplitDataInBlocks(dataExample);
        // groups.size().ShouldBe(2)
        // groups[0].ShouldBeEquals("HEADER SOME POSITIONAL DATA
        //                            BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR1 2018-06-18
        //                            BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR2 2018-05-15
        //                            FOOTER POSITINAL DATA")
        //
        //groups[1].ShouldBeEquals("HEADER SOME POSITIONAL DATA 2
        //                          BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR1 XXXX - XX - XX
        //                          BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR2 XXXX - XX - XX
        //                          BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR3 XXXX - XX - XX
        //                          BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR4 XXXX - XX - XX
        //                          FOOTER POSITINAL DATA 2)

        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            // Load all file data
            var allFileData = sr.ReadToEnd();

            // Method suposed split entire string in a list of blocks --- This is the question
            List<string> groups = SplitDataInBlocks(allFileData);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                // Read the group and do something
                ProcessGroup(group);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its not clear what your desired output would be.  Can you provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Do you want to have a `List<string>` such that everything from `Header1` to `Header2` is in the first entry, `Header2` to `Header3` in the second, and from the last header to the footer in the final entry?

Comment: @maccettura, i added expected result in snipet code. Thanks

Comment: @FernandoFigueiredo what would be in `groups[1]`?

Comment: @ivcubr, I have now updated the snipetcode with the expected result of groups [1].

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to loop through all the lines and check for where you have your header/footers.

```
string dataExample = @"
    HEADER SOME POSITIONAL DATA
    BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR1 2018-06-18
    BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR2 2018-05-15
    FOOTER POSITINAL DATA
    HEADER SOME POSITIONAL DATA 2
    BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR1 XXXX-XX-XX
    BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR2 XXXX-XX-XX
    BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR3 XXXX-XX-XX
    BODY POSITIONAL FOO BAR4 XXXX-XX-XX
    FOOTER POSITINAL DATA 2";

string[] strings = dataExample.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
List<string> result = new List<string>();
string current = "";
foreach (string s in strings) {
    current += s;

    if (s.Contains("FOOTER")) {
        result.Add(current);
        current = "";
    }
}
if (current.Length != 0) {
    result.Add(current);
}
```

This gives you a list with two entries but does not preserve existing line breaks. Note that you cannot simply use `String.Split("FOOTER")` since this does not keep the header/footer text in place.